# ion library json query

Tags: android, json

I am making app and getting stuck just because of json it is taking "" comma on overall json so my request is being fail so check code and help me 
thanks.

```
        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(                                                                                               
            new Runnable() {                                                                                                            
                public void run() {                                                                                                     
                    JSONObject jsobj=new JSONObject();                                                                                  
                    JSONObject jsobj1=new JSONObject();                                                                                 
                    try {                                                                                                               
                        jsobj1.put("mobile",_mobileText.getText().toString());                                                          
                        jsobj1.put("s","payment");                                                                                  
                        jsobj1.put("cl","sample_client");                                                                         
                        jsobj.put("pa",jsobj);                                                                                     
                    } catch (JSONException e) {                                                                                         
                        e.printStackTrace();                                                                                            
                    }                                                                                                                   
   Ion.with(SignupActivity.this)                                                                                                        
                            .load("POST", UrlConfigFile.BASE_URL)                                                                       
                            .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")                                                               
                            .addHeader("clientKey","sample_client")                                                                     

                            .asJsonObject()                                                                                             
                            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {                                                             
                                @Override                                                                                               
                                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {                                               
                                    if(e!=null)                                                                                         
                                    {                                                                                                   
                                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
                                    }else                                                                                               
                                    {                                                                                                   
                                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "working "+result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                                        onSignupSuccess();                                                                              

                                    }                                                                                                   

                                }                                                                                                       
                            });                                                                                                         

                    // onSignupFailed();                                                                                                
                    progressDialog.dismiss();                                                                                           
                }                                                                                                                       
            }, 3000);
```

json would be like this 
{
"object":{
          "key":"value",
          "key":"value"
             },
"key":"value"
}